# my destroy action is not redirecting me back to full event list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails

destroy action is destroying event, but it does not redirect me back to full event list.
i have same redirect_to in update and new actions and it works just fine

also in destroy, update and new   this flash.now[] and flash[] are not working

error message

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /events/6
Couldn't find Event with 'id'=6
```

of course it can't find it when it is deleted but why is that? and how should i fix it. i even tried putting redirect before deleting but doesn't work

and on right side it shows that line 18 in events_controller is wrong which is @event = Event.find(params[:id]) in show action

events controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    if @event.save
      flash[:notice] = "Event created!"
      redirect_to events_url
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Event not created!"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])

    if @event.update(event_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Event updated!"
      redirect_to events_url
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Event not updated!"
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event.destroy
    redirect_to events_url
    flash[:alert] = "Event deleted successfully"
  end

  private

    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_date, :end_date, :venue, :location)
    end
end
```

i have tried events_url, events_path, @events but none works

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @event.title %></h1>

<div>
  <p><%= @event.description %></p>

  <p><%= @event.start_date %></p>

  <p><%= @event.end_date %></p>

  <p><%= @event.venue %></p>

  <p><%= @event.location %></p>

</div>


<p><%= link_to "Edit Event", edit_event_path(@event) %> | <%= link_to "Delete Event", event_path(@event),data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Sure?"} %></p>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events   # Define your application routes per the DSL in 
  path route ("/")   # root "articles#index" 
end
```

delete error log

```
Started GET "/events/9" for ::1 at 2022-03-17 17:39:15 +0100
Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
  [1m[36mEvent Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:7:in `show'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering events/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered events/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 133)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 13.0ms | Allocations: 3856)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 13.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 4668)


Started DELETE "/events/9" for ::1 at 2022-03-17 17:39:17 +0100
Processing by EventsController#destroy as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
  [1m[36mEvent Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:42:in `destroy'
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `destroy'
  [1m[36mEvent Destroy (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[31mDELETE FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ?[0m  [["id", 9]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `destroy'
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (1.9ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:43:in `destroy'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/events
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms | Allocations: 2423)


Started DELETE "/events" for ::1 at 2022-03-17 17:39:17 +0100
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/events"):
  
Started GET "/events/9" for ::1 at 2022-03-17 17:39:17 +0100
Processing by EventsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
  [1m[36mEvent Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/events_controller.rb:7:in `show'
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 1355)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Event with 'id'=9:
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:7:in `show'

Started POST "/__better_errors/f10d80ad70fa11f1/variables" for ::1 at 2022-03-17 17:39:18 +0100
```

in folder javascript
application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
```

and in that folder is another one folder called controllers with this 3 files

application.js

```
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

hello_controllers.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.element.textContent = "Hello World!"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
// Import and register all your controllers from the importmap under controllers/*

import { application } from "controllers/application"

// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)

// Lazy load controllers as they appear in the DOM (remember not to preload controllers in import map!)
// import { lazyLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
// lazyLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

Comment: routes.rb code
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :events
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
`

Comment: In the future -- edit your question -- don't put code in comments.

Comment: i hope i added right thing, its my first time on stackoverflow. And sorry for posting code in comments before!!

Comment: If you look at your log -- it deletes and redirects properly, but then it makes a another DELETE /events call and another GET call trying to show the event you just deleted.  By any chance have some javascript on this page?

Comment: I added all .js files

Comment: your problem is likely the @hotwired/stimulus  doing eagerLoadControllersFrom. Comment out the import and eagerlLoadControllers lines

Comment: when i comment it, delete link does not work

Comment: change turbo_method: :delete,  to method: :delete and turbo_confirm: "Sure?", confirm: "Sure?"

Comment: still delete doesnt work, tried it with commented js also doesnt work